# QGraphicsView Image printed lost line definitions

Tags: c++, qt5, qgraphicsview

I'm using QGraphicsView and QGraphicsScene to draw a QGraphicsPixmap. This QGraphicsPixmap contains a jpg image with 10652 x 14204 of resolution.

When I display it on QGraphicsView i received this image:

[image: QGraphicsView Display Image]

As you can see, lines are jagged and with low definition. I show the same image on Windows Photos Viewer and IrfanView and this effect does not appear as you can see below:

[image: Image display on Windows Photos]

I tried using this flags of QGraphicsView but I obtain the same result:

```
pictureGraphicsView = new QGraphicsView(this);
scene = new QGraphicsScene(pictureGraphicsView);
pictureGraphicsView->setScene(scene);
pictureGraphicsView->setRenderHints(QPainter::Antialiasing| QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform
                                 | QPainter::TextAntialiasing);

pictureGraphicsView->setViewportUpdateMode(QGraphicsView::FullViewportUpdate);
```

Someone knows if it's posible avoid this effect on QGraphicsView?

Comment: You draw the pixmap using [QGraphicsPixmapItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicspixmapitem.html)? (I missed that in your exposed code.)
Assuming Yes: _You can set the pixmap's transformation mode by calling setTransformationMode(). By default, Qt::FastTransformation is used, which provides fast, non-smooth scaling. Qt::SmoothTransformation enables QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform on the painter, and the quality depends on the platform and viewport. The result is usually not as good as calling QPixmap::scale() directly._ (from doc.)

Comment: Hi @Scheff'sCat, Thanks for your reply! As you said, i use a QGraphicsPixmapItem for Draw the image  with this code:                                                    
      QGraphicsPixmapItem * pix = new QGraphicsPixmapItem();
    pix->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
    pix->setTransformationMode(Qt::SmoothTransformation);
    scene->addItem(pix);                                                                                                                  I had the Qt::SmoothTransformation flag but had or no it dont have any effect.

Comment: Ah, OK. I don't have experience how seriously the last part is meant: _the quality depends on the platform and viewport_ Maybe, more seriously as I did imagine. Have you tried alternatively to render (a sub-rectangle of) the `QPixmap` with `QPainter` yourself, considering the hint with the `QPixmap::scale()`?